# WCF Service: MaxReceivedMessageSize (async)

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, streaming

I ran into an exception because the message size and/or array-length of data that I'm transmitting from a WCF server to a client exceeds the maximum size. This topic occurs quite often, but most solutions are about changing the MaxReceivedMessageSize of the service binding.

```
    var binding = new WSHttpBinding { MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue };
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEditor), binding, uri);
```

But I’m interested how this can be resolved in a different way. Consider the following method. It might result in a large byte array. I also tried converting the image into a Base64String.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEditor
{
    [OperationContract]
    byte[] GetImage();
}
```

Is there a common pattern to use **BeginRead/EndRead** for streaming the byte array in smaller chunks to the client? How would you do that in code?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft (see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) the contract has to be adjusted and the end-point configuration as well.

```
<system.serviceModel>
     …
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ExampleBinding" transferMode="Streaming"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
     …
<system.serviceModel>

[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
public interface IStreamedService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream Echo(Stream data);
    [OperationContract]
    Stream RequestInfo(string query);
    [OperationContract(OneWay=true)]
    void ProvideInfo(Stream data);
}
```